# CUDA: running programs with OpenMP

Tags: concurrency, cuda, openmp

Is it possible to run program with openMP on GPU using CUDA or something else?

I have a concurrency program, but my computer have only 2 cores.

I need to test program on 8 and more cores.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Future OpenMP versions are likely to merge accelerators support but for now your only option is to run with more threads than CPU cores.

Comment: is it normal? i have 2 cores and run program with 4 or 8. and result was the same :\

Comment: Well, you won't get any real speed-up (worse, you'll get a slowdown because of the added overhead) but at least you can confirm that your code works with 8 threads.

Comment: uh, it won't help me :\ i need to know REAL acceleration like if i run program on 8 cores :\ thanks for explanation!

Comment: Then find a real 8-core machine and run on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [OpenACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) which is kind of similar to OpenMP, although of course adapted to the very different asymmetric situation of CPU+GPU.

If your purpose however is to test OpenMP code, the answer is a definite NO. You can't take the same program, and it would not execute the same way anyway.

Your best bet probably is to execute the OpenMP program with OMP_NUM_THREADS=8, which will start 8 threads even if only 2 cores are available. Some aspects (e.g. lock contention) will still be different from a real 8 core system though.